# Can I Log data using NSArray, then show it in UITableView?

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdate, uistoryboard

So I want to use an NSArray to log data and display that data on a TableView. Can I use the NSArray to add a new entry to the array every time the data is changed? Let me explain myself better. I have a value that is 80. Then, the user changes it to 120. I want to store in the array the difference (20) and the date as an entry, so then I could display it in a table view... Don't know if it makes sense for you...

Comment: Sure.  You can log the data any way you want, and display it any way you want.  It's all software.

Comment: your answer is "yes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.

Here's one way to do it (of more than countably many ways, as a mathematician would say)

Create a class LogEntry. Give it a value property and a date property. Then allocate a mutable array, and create LogEntry objects with the edits and add them to your array of logged changes. If the table view is on-screen, send it a reload message to get it to update it's data.

Comment: I'll try to use this. I'm just a newbie iOS developer, but I want to learn, so... Thanks! :)